# PostgreSQL Query that excludes two values

Tags: sql, postgresql

How can I write a query where I want to exlude 'Coconut' & 'Kiwi' from the Sweet_Fruits column when Tropical_Fruits column = Yes

| Sweet_Fruits | Tropical_Fruits |
| --- | --- |
| Coconut | Yes |
| Pear | No |
| Kiwi | Yes |
| Peach | No |

Expected result

| Sweet_Fruits | Tropical_Fruits |
| --- | --- |
| Pear | No |
| Peach | No |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `WHERE` condition with `OR` as follows:

```
select * 
  from your_table
 where Sweet_Fruits not in ('Coconut','Kiwi') or Tropical_Fruits <> 'Yes'
```